# Is it possible to hide some fields from our model?

Tags: android, model, android-room

I decided to use Room for caching data and now because of the situation of the library that I developed, I need to hide some fields of my model and then give them to the client that use my library.

The model below had `orderId` and I added this because I need that but when I don't want to give this filled model with `orderId`. i know how to ignore fields in `JSON`. But how can i hide this one from my model and then give it to the client.

> Do I make a mistake in using Room in the first place?

```
public class Participant {
@PrimaryKey
private long id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "order_id")
private long orderId;

private long threadId;

private String name;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
```

For example :

i have a listener that is like the below

```
listener.add(participant);
```

i want to hide `orderId` first and then pass it to the listener.

Then in another class override this:

```
@Override
public void onAdd(Paticipant participant) {
    super.onAdd(participant);
    //here 
}
```

Comment: Hi, just so I understand your requirements; you want to hide `orderId` from classes that make use of Participant?

Comment: @EamonScullion yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

One way to hide `orderId` from classes which use Participant, is to provide a getter for this variable and return null:

```
public Long getOrderId() {
    return null;
}
```

We must change `orderId` to a `Long` in order for it to be set as null.

Additionally, you can override the `toString()` method to ignore `orderId` in any string representations of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Use GSON library and create a new class for JSON model, without `orderId`:

```
class ParticipantJson {
    final long id;
    final long threadId;
    final String name;
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;

    // Constructor
}
```

Then you can create JSON representation with:

```
ParticipantJson participant = new ParticipantJson(/* fields from Room model */);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(participant);
```

Comment: Thank you but like i said before i need to give model object not Json String.

Answer (score 0):

USE A DIFFERENT MODEL FOR PRESENTATION!

Sorry for the caps but I cannot emphasize how important it is to use a **different** model for presentation. 
Although you can hide fields from libraries like `GSON` or `ROOM` using keywords like `transient` or annotation like `ignore` you cannot hide a model attribute from class itself. Also remember that you cannot **enforce** a rule on a model that is not **designed** for the purpose.

**TLDR;** Create a new model and using a **mapper** map the `Room` model to this new presentation model.